# Linkedin return Uncaught Error: JavaScript API Domain is restricted to

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the linkedin API, but without success,

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: 86fzwyid3r60fe
        authorize: true
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    </script>
</head>
```

I receive the error:

> Uncaught Error: JavaScript API Domain is restricted to www.miweb.com

I have already added the domain in my Javascript configuration and I have also saved the changes, however, I always receive the error

Answer (score 1):

When you create your linkedin application (https://www.linkedin.com/developer/apps)

Be sure to add the relevant javascript domains here:

[image]